# Object for every line of text

Tags: java, oop, io

```
public class library {
  library() {
    ArrayList<book> books = new ArrayList<book>();
  }

public void read() throws Exception {
    String thisLine = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:/booklist.txt"));
        while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(thisLine);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    library lib = new library();
    lib.read();
}
}
```

I'm reading the titles of various books from the text file and I need to create a separate book class object for every title (line of text). This class has only one attribute - String title. I'd use your help guys ;)

Comment: What prevents you from creating the `Book` class?

Comment: Yeah, why dont you create a book class?

Comment: I need a method that creates multiple book class objects, each with different string content

Comment: Read the basics of OO programming first.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void read() throws Exception {
    String thisLine = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:/booklist.txt"));
        while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(thisLine);
            Book b = new Book(thisLine);
            books.add(b);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

so you will have an arraylist full of books identified by title

Comment: I do not think this was OP's question.

Comment: at every line the code will generate a new book and add it to the arraylist, it's not the same book with the same title, it's a list of books, you have to learn more about Collections

Comment: His approach is right, what do you actually need @AndrzejStempnik

Answer (score 1):

Your`Book` class should look something like this:

```
public class Book {

    String title;

    public Book(String title) { //constructor
        this.title = title; //sets the value of title to the String passed to the constructor
    }
}
```

The answer posted by Oussema Aroua shows how you can then create your `ArrayList` of `Book` objects utilizing this class.